# How can we sort wave report by number column?

Tags: reporting, einstein-analytics, sort, einstein

I have created a Wave Report which I need to sort by Number field. I am not able to add Formula(Number) in Group by column even with using SAQL.

I have already tried the workaround to change Formula(Number) to Formula(Text) but Salesforce sort text field as alphanumeric sort and not natural sort so it doesn't work for me.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The guide clearly mentions to use order by for sorting and not grouping .

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_statement_order.htm

[image]

You will need to use order by clause  in your saql

Comment: Hi Mohith, Yes, you can sort by text and date field using order by clause but when I try adding number field, its giving me exception.

Comment: I am getting Unknown IDTOKEN: exception when I try to add the number field in order by clause.